# Keeping a mesh flush against another surface without ruining geometry (Non-Spherical Eyes)

Tags: animation, rigging

I am working on a cartoon style animated character who has unrealistic non-spherical eyes.
`Warning, it looks really dumb from this angle.` 
[image: Eyes]

The problem is that because the eyes of my character are not spherical, attempting to move the iris and pupil simply by rotating the eye is not possible. I am now trying to figure out a way to manipulate the iris & pupil separately. However, when moving the eyes it is almost impossible to keep the surfaces together, but shrink wrapping causes the geometry to warp.

I would really appreciate some help and suggestions on how to get this to work. Thank you.

Comment: First rig the eyes as spheres, then use a lattice modifier to deform them into the head shape.

Comment: @sambler Hey, thanks for your response, that is a really clever idea. However, it doesn't quite seem to work in my case, perhaps I misunderstood. [Here is what my attempt looked like](https://gfycat.com/UntidyImmediateKilldeer)